# AWS Fargate - fails health check while instance is up

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I am a similar question to some posts, but none of the specific issues relate as far as I can tell. I will post my stack later in this post.

I have:

```
ALB----->Listener->target group->Fargate service->task definition
80/http           ->8080/http                   -> 8080/http
```

The problem is my health checks fail. When the Fargate task spins up an instance, I can go to that instance using the health check URL, and i get a 200 response.  however, any attempt to go through the load balancer results in a gateway timeout.

```
$ curl -fv http://172.31.47.18:8080/healthz
*   Trying 172.31.47.18...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.31.47.18 (172.31.47.18) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /healthz HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.31.47.18:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2019 15:33:39 GMT
< Server: Warp/3.2.27
< 
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.47.18 left intact
OK
```

However, the health check never passes on the LB.

1. the security group used for every thing right now is wide open. I wanted to eliminate that as an issue.
2. the fargate nodes are set up for public IPs.

This has been driving me crazy for the last couple of days. I stood up an EC2 backed ECS, and everything works on EC2.  I should point out that the entire stack builds just fine in Fargate, except for not getting any traffic either from the load balancer or something.

The error in the service events says

```
service test-graph (port 8080) is unhealthy in target-group tg--test-graph due to (reason Request timed out).
```

Hopefully someone has an idea.

```
  TaskDef0:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn: Cluster0
    Properties:
      ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/ECS_Hasura_Execution_Role
      TaskRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
      Family: !Ref 'ServiceName'
      Cpu: !FindInMap
                - ContainerSizeMap
                - !Ref ContainerSize
                - Cpu
      Memory: !FindInMap
                   - ContainerSizeMap
                   - !Ref ContainerSize
                   - Memory
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
          Cpu: !FindInMap
                - ContainerSizeMap
                - !Ref ContainerSize
                - Cpu
          Memory: !FindInMap
                   - ContainerSizeMap
                   - !Ref ContainerSize
                   - Memory
          Image: !FindInMap
                - ServiceMap
                - !Ref ServiceProvider
                - ImageUrl
          PortMappings:
            - 
              ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
              HostPort: !Ref ContainerPort
              Protocol: tcp

  ALB0:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    DependsOn: TaskDef0
    Properties: 
      Name: !Join
              - '-'
              - - lb-
                - !Ref ServiceName
      Scheme: internet-facing
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      LoadBalancerAttributes: 
        - Key: deletion_protection.enabled
          Value: false
        - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
          Value: 60
        - Key: routing.http.drop_invalid_header_fields.enabled
          Value: false
        - Key: routing.http2.enabled
          Value: true
      SecurityGroups: 
        - sg-xxxxxx # allow HTTP/HTTPS to the load balancer
      Subnets: 
        - subnet-111111
        - subnet-222222
        - subnet-333333
      Type: application

  targetGroup0:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    DependsOn: ALB0
    Properties: 
      Name: !Join
              - '-'
              - - tg-
                - !Ref ServiceName
      Port: !Ref TargetGroupPort
      Protocol: !Ref TargetGroupProtocol    
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !FindInMap
                - ServiceMap
                - !Ref ServiceProvider
                - VpcId
      # all other paraneters can be changed without interruption
      HealthCheckPort: traffic-port
      HealthCheckEnabled: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - HealthCheckEnabled
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - HealthCheckIntervalSeconds
      HealthCheckPath: !FindInMap
                - ServiceMap
                - !Ref ServiceProvider
                - HealthCheckPath
      HealthCheckProtocol: !FindInMap
                - ServiceMap
                - !Ref ServiceProvider
                - HealthCheckProtocol
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds
      HealthyThresholdCount: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - HealthyThresholdCount
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - UnhealthyThresholdCount
      Matcher: 
        HttpCode: !FindInMap
                - ServiceMap
                - !Ref ServiceProvider
                - HealthCheckSuccessCode
      TargetGroupAttributes: 
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - DeregistrationDelay
        - Key: slow_start.duration_seconds
          Value: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - SlowStart
        - Key: stickiness.enabled
          Value: !FindInMap
                - LBTGMap
                - Parameters
                - Stickiness

  Listener0:
    # This is the fixed response test listener
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: ALB0
    Properties:   
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: fixed-response      
          FixedResponseConfig: 
            ContentType: text/html
            MessageBody: <h1>Working</h1><p>The load balancer test listener is operational</p>
            StatusCode: 200
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB0
      Port: 9000
      Protocol: HTTP

  Listener1:
    # This is the port 80 listener
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: ALB0
    Properties:   
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref targetGroup0
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB0
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  Listener2:
    # This is the port 8080 listener
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: ALB0
    Properties:   
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref targetGroup0
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB0
      Port: 8080
      Protocol: HTTP

  Listener3 :
    # This is the port 443 listener
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: ALB0
    Properties:   
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !FindInMap
                - CertificateMap
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - CertifcateArn  
      DefaultActions: 
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref targetGroup0
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ALB0
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS

  Service0:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: Listener2
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster0
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: !FindInMap
                - ECSServiceMap
                - Parameters
                - MaximumPercent
        MinimumHealthyPercent: !FindInMap
                - ECSServiceMap
                - Parameters
                - MinimumHealthyPercent
      DesiredCount: !Ref 'DesiredTaskCount'
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups: # this is allow all ports and IPs
            - !FindInMap
                - SecurityGroupMap
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - sg0
          Subnets:
            - !FindInMap
                - SubnetMap
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - subnet0
            - !FindInMap
                - SubnetMap
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - subnet1
            - !FindInMap
                - SubnetMap
                - !Ref AWS::Region
                - subnet2
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'TaskDef0'
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
          ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'targetGroup0'
      Tags: 
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref "Application"
        - Key: Customer
          Value: !Ref "Customer"
        - Key: Role
          Value: !Ref "Role"
        - Key: InternetAccessible
          Value: !Ref "InternetAccessible"
        - Key: CreationDate
          Value: !Ref "CreationDate"
        - Key: CreatedBy
          Value: !Ref "CreatedBy"

Mappings:
  ServiceMap:
    GraphQL-Ohio: 
      ImageUrl: xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hasura/graphql-engine
      HealthCheckPath: /healthz
      HealthCheckSuccessCode: 200
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      VpcId: vpc-xxxxx

  LBTGMap:
    Parameters:
      HealthCheckEnabled: True
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      DeregistrationDelay: 300
      SlowStart: 0
      Stickiness: false

  SubnetMap: # There is technical debt here to keep this up to date as subnets change
    us-east-2:
      subnet0: subnet-111111
      subnet1: subnet-222222
      subnet2: subnet-333333

  SecurityGroupMap: 
    us-east-2: 
      sg0: sg-xxxxx
```

Comment: This is still a problem.  It has to be with the target group/health check but i dont know what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I figured this out.  I had my HealthCheckPort set to traffic-port.  The string literal "traffic-port", not the actual port number.  Duh.